# including bootstrap in django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project on Django and I want to include bootstrap to it to make it a responsive website.My bootstrap CSS works perfectly fine. Each time I include it`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">`
but when I try to do the same thing for js in bootstrap,it doesn't seem to work,

**Here's my js**

`<script src="https://ajax.gogglepis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>` and here's my file structure
home

```
{%load staticfiles%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nexton's Web</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width , initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet"href{%static'font/glyphiconshalfingsregular.woff2'%}">
<script src="https://ajax.gogglepis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<style>
</style>
</head>                             
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
         <div class="container-fluid">
                         <div class="navbar-header">
                             <button type="button" class="navbartoggle"data-toggle="collaspe" data-target="#MyNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

                         </div>
                         </div>
</nav>
```

and in my setting my STATIC_URL ='/static/'

Comment: Just a few question. 1.) Can you include what your file structure for your app looks like? 2.) What is your `STATIC_URL` set to? 3.) When you run your app, what path does the browser try to find your static files at?

Comment: what is not working? : What does the script tag look like? Where is located your bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: @Austin A ,i just edited my question..thanks